# How to create a elasticsearch document document via URL(http)

Tags: api, elasticsearch

I am new to elasticsearch and trying to find a way to create a document from url(http-API). I have tried below given  options but none of them worked.

```
    http://Myserver:9200/dilbert/user/3 -d '{ "name" : "Praveena" }
    http://Myserver:9200/dilbert/user/3{ "name" : "Praveena" }
    http://Myserver:9200/dilbert/user/3?pretty _create name=Praveena
```

I expect this to add a record. Here dilbert is Index name. user is type & 3 is id. This index only contains a single element called name.

Answer (score 0):

First option should work, but you must explicitly set request type to `PUT`.

It seems to me that you use `curl` to insert data. If you send data to server with `-d` option, `curl` issues the `POST` request by default. But you specify id of document in URL, so Elasticsearch waits for `PUT` request (see [official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html#docs-index_)). You can use `POST` requests only in case of [automatic ID generation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html#_automatic_id_generation).

So your request may look as follows:

```
curl -X PUT http://Myserver:9200/dilbert/user/3 -d '{ "name" : "Praveena" }'
```

Comment: Thanks for replying Alex. I am getting this reply from system. 
  {"_index":"dilbert","_type":"user","_id":"3 -d '{ \"name\" : \"Praveena\" }'","found":false}